# Let $X$ be the number of $1$s and let $Y$ be the number of $2$s obtained. What is the joint PMF of $X$ and $Y$.

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, problem-solving, conditional-probability

I was reading [Introduction to Probability, 2nd Edition](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/188652923X) and the following problem appears on page 128:

> Consider four independent rolls of a 6-sided die.
>
> Let $X$ be the number of $1$s and let $Y$ be the number of $2$s obtained.
>
> What is the joint PMF of $X$ and $Y$?

My reasoning to solve the problem is as follows:

We need $P_{X,Y}(x, y)$.

Let us compute the probability of having $x + y \ $ $1s$ or $2s$ first, it is:
$${}_4 \mathrm{ C }_{x+y} \cdot \left(\frac{2}{6}\right)^{x+y} \cdot \left(\frac{4}{6}\right)^{4-(x + y)}$$

Now out of the $x + y$ $1$s or $2$s the probability of having $x \space 1s$ is:

$${}_{x + y} \mathrm{ C }_{x} \cdot \left( \frac{1}{2} \right)^{x + y}$$

And the final answer is the product of the two probabilities.

Is my reasoning wrong? and if so then what is my mistake?

Comment: First, specifying the bounds would be important: $x, y \geq 0$, $x + y \leq 4$ (outside of which the pmf is zero). Your approach uses a conditional probability approach. Your reasoning seems right, but expressing it directly probably seems a bit simpler. The probability that $X = x$ and $Y = y$ is choosing $x$ out of $4$ dice to roll a $1$, and choosing $y$ out of the remaining $4 - x$ dice to roll a $2$, both w.p. $1/6$. The remaining $4 - (x + y)$ dice are not $1$ or $2$ w.p. $4/6$. This gives the same expression you have (if you multiply it out).

Comment: @JKL Indeed I must specify the bounds but I dropped them here because what I really care about is the reasoning, not the notations.
I know about the answer you explained, but I don't need solutions to the problem, I need to know if my approach is correct or not.

Comment: I did comment on your approach. What makes you think your approach is not correct?

Answer (score 1):

The two marginals are binomial but they are not independent thus to show the joint distribution is better to  use a table-representation.

As an example, here below is the joint distribution related to 2 independent rolls of a die... you can easy do the same work for $n=4$. The resulting table is a triangular matrix...

|  | Y=0 | Y=1 | Y=2 | Total |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **X=0** | p(0;0) | p(0;1) | p(0;2) | 25/36 |
| **X=1** | p(1;0) | p(1;1) | 0 | 10/36 |
| **X=2** | p(2;0) | 0 | 0 | 1/36 |
| **Total** | 25/36 | 10/36 | 1/36 | 1/36 |

I think it is easy for you to calculate the probabilties in the body of the table which have to sum both per column and per row to the binomial probabilities

Comment: I do not understand where the wrong is?
Is splitting the problem into calculating first the presence of 1s or 2s as one outcome wrong or what?